# Wrong vtable inside the overloaded operator function when using std::set:insert

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, vtable, stdset

I ran into a weird isue with virtual meshods when i call them from '<' overloaded operator.
As you allready know, in order to used the std::set I must to define propper comparision operator into the element class. But in my case this class have few derived forms(There are few diffrent class how inherit from this element base class) So the set may contains elements of diffrents derived types.

The problem comes when I try to using virtual meshods into the operator function's block[I doing this in order to decide which element is greater depend on the derived class type]. **When I doing this the base class meshod is called insted of the overriding one!**.

I did some debuging work and I found that from some reason the operator functions' arguments sometime lose their orginal derived type.

I would appriciate an explanation why this happening.
I'm starting to wonder if the insertion process is copying the elements data into a new ones without the derived type.

This is my code:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>

class Base
{
    public:
        std::string name;
    public:
        Base() { name = "Base"; }

        virtual void DummyVirtualFunction() {};//For enable the vtable
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        Derived() : Base() { name = "Drived"; }
};

bool operator<(const Base& first, const Base& secound)
{
    Base base_instance      = Base();
    Derived drived_instance = Derived();

    long base_vtable    = *((long*)&(base_instance));   //The Vtable-Pointer-Value(x64) of Base
    long drived_vtable  = *((long*)&(drived_instance)); //The Vtable-Pointer-Value(x64) of Derived

    long first_vtable   = *((long*)&first);             //The Vtable-Pointer-Value(x64) of the 'first'
    long secound_vtable = *((long*)&secound);           //The Vtable-Pointer-Value(x64) of the 'secound'

    printf("first's name is '%s' and its have vtable of the %s \n", first.name.c_str(), (first_vtable == base_vtable) ? "Base. WTF!!!" : "Derived.");
    printf("secound's name is '%s' and its have vtable of the %s \n", secound.name.c_str(), (secound_vtable == base_vtable) ? "Base. WTF!!!" : "Derived.");

    return (void*)&first < (void*)&secound;//Regular pointers comperation
}

void main()
{
    std::set<Base> set;
    set.insert(Derived());
    set.insert(Derived());//The secound insertion calls to the '<' operator in order to arange the set nodes in the right order
}
```

Sorry about my English.

Comment: You are going to need to use a `std::set<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` if you want polymorphic behavior.

Comment: Instead of a dummy function, define the destructor.

Comment: And instead of the old type-unsafe C function `printf` please use `std::cout`.

Comment: When asking about an issue with code you better tell us about the symptoms rather than your interpretation. With a `std::set<Base>` the vtable is irrelevant. Best include output and expecfted output in the question (and your interpretation and conclusions are good add-ons)

Comment: Also never use pointers the way you're doing it. Virtual tables is a ***very*** implementation-specific thing, and are in fact not required to be there at all.

Comment: Lastly, `set.insert(Derived())` will *slice* the `Derived` object, loosing all `Derived` parts and keeping only the `Base` parts. See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). Your learning material should have taught you that references or pointers are needed, even to *store* polymorphic objects.

Comment: `//The Vtable-Pointer-Value(x64) of Base` -- I hate to throw cold water on this, but you need to start from scratch and assume there is no such thing as a "Vtable-Pointer".  There are canonical ways to achieve what you are trying to achieve without all of the casting, pointer manipulation, etc.

Comment: *"So the set may contains elements of diffrents derived types"* -- Nope. A set contains elements of exactly one type.